# delete observations with less than X consecutive dates

Tags: python, pandas

the following dataframe which contains data for the same company (column ID) at different dates (column date). I would like to delete the observations for which there are less than 3 days.

The starting dataset is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":4,"5":4,"6":4,"7":2,"8":2,"9":3,"10":3},
    "date":{"0":1421020800000,"1":1421193600000,"2":1422489600000,"3":1423353600000,"4":1421020800000,"5":1421107200000,"6":1421193600000,"7":1421020800000,"8":1421107200000,"9":1421452800000,"10":1421539200000},
    "variable":{"0":28,"1":62,"2":60,"3":72,"4":28,"5":61,"6":62,"7":23,"8":70,"9":32,"10":55}})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='ms')
df.sort_values(by=["ID", "date"],inplace=True)
```

In the above dataframe, only company with ID = 4 satisfies the requirement and I would like to delete the others.

I wrote the following code but it has an obvious problem and I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
df['delete'] = 0
for name, group in df.groupby(by = "ID"):
    if group.shape[0] < 3:
        df.loc[df['ID']==name,'delete'] = 1
df = df.loc[df['delete'] == 0,:]
```

The above code keeps both companies with ID=1 and ID=4; ID=1 should be cancelled because it contains 4 datapoints but at maximum two of them are on consecutive days (while I want to impose a minimum of 3).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC using `diff` + `cumsum`  with `date` column  create the group key New, then we just using `groupby` + `filter` the unwanted groups

```
df['New']=df.groupby('ID').date.apply(lambda x : x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum())
yourdf=df.groupby(['ID','New']).filter(lambda x : len(x)>=3)
yourdf
Out[809]: 
   ID       date  variable  New
4   4 2015-01-12        28    1
5   4 2015-01-13        61    1
6   4 2015-01-14        62    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could replace the "group.shape[0]" applying a moving window of 3 days and count items.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":4,"5":4,"6":4,"7":2,"8":2,"9":3,"10":3},
    "date":{"0":1421020800000,"1":1421193600000,"2":1422489600000,"3":1423353600000,"4":1421020800000,"5":1421107200000,"6":1421193600000,"7":1421020800000,"8":1421107200000,"9":1421452800000,"10":1421539200000},
    "variable":{"0":28,"1":62,"2":60,"3":72,"4":28,"5":61,"6":62,"7":23,"8":70,"9":32,"10":55}})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='ms')
df.sort_values(by=["ID", "date"],inplace=True)

df['delete'] = 0
for name, group in df.groupby(by = "ID"):
    group.set_index('date',inplace=True)

    if group.rolling(window='3D',min_periods=0).count()['delete'].max() < 3:
        df.loc[df['ID']==name,'delete'] = 1
df = df.loc[df['delete'] == 0,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['delete'] = 0
for name, group in df.groupby(by = "ID"):
    if group.shape[0] != 3:
        df.loc[df['ID']==name,'delete'] = 1
df = df.loc[df['delete'] == 0,:]
```

you may set wrong in `if group.shape[0] != 3`